# Serverless variable interpolation env:VAR fallback using Fn::GetAtt

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

When using the serverless framework to deploy my application, my staging/production environments use the respective ElasticCache instances spun up as part of the resources required for the application and the endpoint is set as an environment variable.

```
  environment:
    REDIS_URL:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - 'redis://'
          - Fn::GetAtt: [ElasticCacheCluster, RedisEndpoint.Address]
```

The above implementation works fine, but when using `serverless-offline` this obviously doesn't get a real Endpoint and REDIS_URL ends up as `redis://[object Object]`.

What I would like to do is use `env:REDIS_URL` if present, and if not, set it using Fn::GetAtt as above.

Given the normal fallback syntax is `${env:REDIS_URL, fallback}` I assumed I'd be able to use some form of the above Fn:GetAtt but I can't seem to get the syntax to work.

```
  environment:
    REDIS_URL: ${env:REDIS_URL,
      { Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - 'redis://'
          - Fn::GetAtt: [ElasticCacheCluster, RedisEndpoint.Address] }
    }
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the Fn:Join elsewhere then referring to it in the environment configuration as a fallback seems to work.

```
provider:
  environment:
    REDIS_URL: ${env:REDIS_URL, self:custom.REDIS_URL}
custom:
  REDIS_URL:
    Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - 'redis://'
        - Fn::GetAtt: [ElasticCacheCluster, RedisEndpoint.Address]
```